# Iterative jump info converged error during findbugs analysis in sonar

Tags: java, jenkins, findbugs, sonarqube

I am getting following error during analyzing our code by findbugs in sonar:

```
> Iterative jump info converged after 24 iterations in 
> static <methodName>, size 4535
```

When I run findbugs analysis locally or in Jenkins there is no error and also findbugs report 0 violations. However if I run findbugs analysis of the code in sonar, it reports violations which are excluded by findbugs-exclude.xml.

Could anybody advice what can causing this error or what it really means? I was able to find the relevant piece of findbugs code producing it [here](http://findbugs.googlecode.com/git-history/463e232cc06da3940f48b61874c306ddf65c6d2b/findbugs/src/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/OpcodeStack.java) however it is getting no sense to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Really, nobody ever had this problem?

Comment: I do have the same problem: “Iterative jump info converged after 21 iterations in static freenet.crypt.ciphers.Rijndael_Algorithm.<clinit>()V, size 3018”. The file in question is https://github.com/freenet/fred/blob/next/src/freenet/crypt/ciphers/Rijndael_Algorithm.java.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you need to reduce the amount of loops (or general complexity) in your static method. Check [this pull request](https://github.com/freenet/fred/pull/296/files) for what I did: move lots of stuff from the static initializer into methods; after that, findbugs runs perfectly.